# open another activity when got a result "success" from php webservice But doesn't work, android

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

I have used a php webservice where i am matching login credentials if true i pass "success", if false i pass "failure".

and In java code, i am matching result data and apply condition when will open another activity and when will show a toast for wrong credentials.

But when i put either wrong or right credentials it will always open another activity. never show a toast

So please help me , what should I do ?

my code

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String str = result.trim();
        if(str=="success") {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class));
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Either Username or Password is not correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

my php code

```
$sql = "select * from master_login_tbl where user_id = '$user' or email='$user' and password = '$pass' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$check = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_of_rows > 0){echo "success";}else{echo 'failure';}
```

Comment: why not using `String.equals` for Strings comparison ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `str.equals("success")`, comparing strings in Java with `==` does not work because you compare the objects and not the string.

You can also use `equalsIgnoreCase("success)"`, which, as the name suggests, ignores any upper or lower case differences.